# How to add Firebase Database Value stored in a model class to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I was trying to add **Firebase Database** value to an ArrayList for later use. I created a model class for this. And then I was trying to add this model class to an **ArrayList**. But for some reason the ArrayList size is 0, that means no data is going to the ArrayList. Why is that? I did that to other activities and it worked, but it's not working here. I added the code snippet here-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityViewProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    ArrayList<Users> user_list = new ArrayList<>(); //Users is the model class

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            user_list.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ss: snapshot.getChildren()){
                Users us = ss.getValue(Users.class);
                user_list.add(us); //adding the model class to the ArrayList
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewProfileActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(user_list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What could be the problem here? The toast shows "0" that means no data whatsoever inside the **ArrayList**. What am I missing here?